# Is it Possible to play GIF or FlASH format images in Monocross Apps?

Tags: c#, animation, monocross

I want to add play gif format to my monocross app. So that it can support in iphone android and windows phone, Could this be done, and how would I do it?

I am new to Monocross Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can play Animated GIF images in Android using a VideoView - so by extension you can also do this in MonoDroid and in MonoCross.

You can't out-of-the-box decode and display GIFs in WindowsPhone - but you can use one of the imaging libraries from nuget. I don't know if any of these work with animated GIFs - I would guess they don't.

---

My gut reaction is to recommend you do **not** use Animated Gifs - sorry, but they're last century tech and should stay there http://www.lingscars.com/ !

Instead, look at using your own stop-frame animations, use short videos or look at coding the animations natively on each platform (I've seen some attempts at cross-platform animations in jscript - e.g. http://speckyboy.com/2012/05/09/jcsml-a-new-cross-platform-animation-library/ - would be cool to see a version in C# too!)